# Reinstall CUDA toolkit on Fresh Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: server, nvidia, 22.04, cuda

I need to be able to get the Nvidia CUDA Toolkit installed. However, whenever I do so, I end up with driver conflicts, requiring a fresh reinstall of Ubuntu to get the GPUs working again.

When I installed Ubuntu, I let it download and install the drivers(including nvidia drivers). While that gives me Cuda 11.4 and updated video drivers that work, it does not include the nvidia cuda toolkit, which I need.

I can reinstall Ubuntu again if needed(done this 3 times already, what's another?) or would gladly type some commands, if they actually worked.

So far I've tried removing the drivers, to no avail because the default nvidia drivers from Ubuntu do not have a remove script.

The GPUs are Tesla K80s. What would you try to get Ubuntu 22.04 with the right drivers + cuda toolkit working?

I am open to ANY suggestions. Should I reinstall Ubuntu with no drivers? If so, how do I go about getting the right drivers(most updated with cuda 11.4) and cuda toolkit installed?

TIA

Comment: You may want to use the Nvidia's script and explicitly tell it to NOT install any drivers.

Comment: @ChanganAuto - ty for your reply. Which script and where can I find it? How can I tell it not to install drivers?

Comment: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit

Comment: @ChanganAuto I tried sudo apt-get install cuda-toolkit-11 -8 as in the guide. However, it gives me "Command line option 8 [from -8] is not understood in combination with the other options."